# How to get result of fs.rename

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using Node.js and the `fs` module. When a file is uploaded, I want to rename it to its original name and log the updated name (original name). My code for renaming an uploaded file works fine. But I am having trouble printing `fileName`.

```
let fileName = "";
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name), function(err) {
        if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        fileName = path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name);
    });
});

let name = fileName;
console.log("NAME " + name);
```

What should I do differently?

**EDIT: This is not a duplicate as the question really is specifically about `fs.rename`, not how to bypass asynchronous property**

Comment: Which line runs first? `fileName = ...` or `console.log("NAME " + fileName)`?

Comment: Is anything logged to console or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: `console.log("NAME " + fileName)` prints only NAME

Comment: The `console.log` in the last line will execute before the callback to `fs.rename`, so the `fileName === ""` at the moment of logging. Move the console.log to the callback function.

Comment: fileName is empty @Kirk

Comment: @pawel I want to use this fileName as a variable in other parts of my code, so if I move it inside then it is out of scope

Comment: maybe I have to use a promise to make sure the callback is done before logging it

Comment: But is it a good practice to use promises in backend server code?

Comment: You can have the variable in whatever scope you want. What matters is that it is assigned the value asynchronously in the callback so it may or may not contain what you expect when accessed later in the program.

Comment: And being async, non-blocking and, by extension, utilising Promises or async/await is kind of the selling point of Node so yes, it is perfectly okay to embrace it in backend code.

Comment: ok solved it using promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With insights from @pawel, I used promises to solve this. I did not know whether it's good practice to use promises on server side Node.js.

```
let fileName = "";
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    form.on('file', function (field, file) {
        fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name), function (err) {
            if (err != null) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            fileName = path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name);
            resolve(fileName);
        });
    });
});

p.then((fileName) => {
    console.log("NAME " + fileName);
});
```

Comment: You should also add `reject(err)` in `if(err != null)`, because now you have unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: @pawel yes you are right. Updated.

Comment: Inside `(field, file) { ... }` it would be easier to do `const fileName = path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name); util.promisify(fs.rename)(file.path, fileName).then(() => resolve(fileName), reject);` Although it would be more efficient to do `const rename = util.promisify(fs.rename)` in the outer scope and just call `rename(file.path, fileName).then(...)` inside the callback.